# Stream map in order to find value of latest key

Tags: java, filter, java-stream, keyset

I have a `Map<Element, Attributes>` consisting of instances of the following (example) class and enum, where I want to get the value of the most recent key via `stream()`. The most recent key can be determined by the property `creationTime` of the class `Element` and the corresponding value in the `Map` is just an `enum` value:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Element implements Comparable<Element> {

    String abbreviation;
    LocalDateTime creationTime;

    public Element(String abbreviation, LocalDateTime creationTime) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }

    public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreationTime() {
        return creationTime;
    }

    public void setCreationTime(LocalDateTime creationTime) {
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Element otherElement) {
        return this.creationTime.compareTo(otherElement.getCreationTime());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + abbreviation + ", " + creationTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) + "]";
    }
}
```

*Please not that an `Element implements Comparable<Element>` just using the built-in comparison of `LocalDateTime`*.

```
public enum Attributes {

    DONE,
    FIRST_REGISTRATION,
    SUBSEQUENT_REGISTRATION
}
```

My current approach is just able to filter the `keySet` and find the most recent key, which I then use to simply get the value in a new line of code. I was wondering if it is possible in a single `stream().filter(...)` statement:

```
Map<Element, Attributes> results = new TreeMap<>();

// filling the map with random elements and attributes

Element latestKey = results.keySet().stream().max(Element::compareTo).get();
Attributes latestValue = results.get(latestKey);
```

> Can we get a value by filtering the `keySet` of a `Map` in a single `stream()` statement like

```
Attributes latestValue = results.keySet().stream()
                .max(Element::compareTo)
                // what can I use here?
                .somehowAccessTheValueOfMaxKey()
                .get()
```

?

**Additional information**
I do not need a default value like `null`, because the `Map` will only be checked if it contains at least one key-value pair, which means there will always be a *most recent* element-attribute pair, a single one, at least.

Comment: I am a bit concerned at the fact that your class doesn't contain an implementation for `equals` and `hashCode`, which may cause the map not to work at all. Also, consider if using `LinkedHashMap` will not save you the need for using this class as a key. If the time stamps merely represent the order of insertion, it may be an easy replacement.

Comment: I omitted the `equals()` method in this example, my original class has one (generated by eclipse). Is anything else wrong with the use of `TreeMap`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Attributes latestValue = results.keySet().stream()
            .max(Element::compareTo)
            .map(results::get)
            .get()
```

Comment: Even less code than in the answer given by @Eran, cool! Thanks, it also seems to get the desired value.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the max `Entry` instead of the max key:

```
Attributes latestValue =
    results.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
           .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
           .get();
```

Comment: I currently prefer the solution provided by @suit because it is less code and has no `.orElse(null)`. I don't need it, which I have edited into the question as additional information at the bottom.

Comment: @deHaar you can replace the orElse(null) with get() if the Map cannot be empty. The advantage of my solution is that it doesn't require an additional Map.get operation. Even though Map.get takes expected time of O(1), it is still faster to obtain the value directly from the Entry instead of searching the Map for the value matching the key.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will have to think about which one is the best answer, they are all good ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Collectors.toMap` with `TreeMap` as a map factory

```
Attributes value = results.entrySet().stream()
       .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v1, TreeMap::new))
       .lastEntry().getValue();
```